# HTML - overflow and position absolute issue

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I have a child with `margin-top`. In order to apply the `margin-top` correctly I need an `overflow` auto for the parent. Unfortunately this overflow auto would cut off overlapping children that had been positioned absolute. Is there a work around?

[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uudhykw/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b">
   <div class="overlap" ></div>
   <p>
    Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds 
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a {  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #005a73;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overlap {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: -60px;
  left: 20px;
}

.b {
  /*overflow: auto; */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 840px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7; 
}

p {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/3uudhykw/2/

Comment: What's your layout supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you might solve the problem.

Wrap your regular content in a separate `div` (`.wrap`) and specify `overflow: auto` on it.

That way, you can still adjust the absolutely positioned element as you want and get the overflow/scroll effect that you need.

See prototype below.

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #005a73;
  height: 100px;
}
.overlap {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: -30px;
  left: 20px;
}
.b {
  position: relative;
}
.b .wrap {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tan;
}
p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
  <div class="overlap"></div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, arula jkasds</p>
  </div>
</div>
```